# How do I add attachments to MOSS list from WSS doc library?

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2007, attachment

Following a recent merge of companies, we are in the process of migrating documents from WSS off one server to MOSS on another, along with reviewing our filing structure.

I've created a list which needs attachments adding to the new items when created, however these are presently stored on WSS as pdfs in a document lirary.  If I browse and add the document to be attached from WSS, it will not accept this as it states "The file or folder name contains characters that are not permitted.  Please use a different name".  Is there a way around this other than downloading the document using xplica to my home drive and then re-uploading them?

Answer (score 0):

So you do "Actions" and "Open with windows explorer" in 1 library and create a new item in a  list and attach files from the same location as in the windows explorer window? Something like http://server/doclib.

I never tried this before but it does work. Interestingly the file that I actually get to upload is from the Internet Explorer temporary internet files. What actual filename do you get to see? That temporary storage does add additional characters to the filename that may be valid for a filesystem but not SharePoint.